# CakePHP 3.x: Spread $conn to associated Tables during Eager Load

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Well I have several databases with the same tables. they are being used in that way by design, to separate continent information.
So I need to change dynamically the connection depends on the user server requested.

Initially I am using something like this:

`$conn = ConnectionManager::get($server);`

`$this->connection($conn);`

but, of course, this change does not spread to the associated Tables.

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my soluction and an alternative approach from an owner of CakePHP

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/6126